# PHP shell_exec user's computer file

Tags: php, command

```
$answer = shell_exec("C:\abc.exe");
echo $answer."</br>";
```

i would like to execute user's computer file.
example : user have to install a abc.exe in their C: drive.
after that they visit my web, and press a button to execute abc.exe in their C drive.
how to implement this coding?

Comment: Not with `shell_exec`, that executes server side. You would need the user to upload the file to your server and then run `shell_exec`.

Comment: Everything in PHP runs on the server, not on the client's computer.

Comment: any command or method able to run user's computer file? maybe javascript?